# How can I connect to an external database with a PhoneGap android app?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am making an android project using PhoneGap for a library system, but I don't know very much about mobile application development. I am using MySQL to create the database and I need to populate HTML pages in my application. How can I do it? I'm not really very sure how to connect to an external database. I want to display existing values in the database as well as add new values from the application.

Comment: Have a look at [Phonegap documentaion.](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/index.html)

Comment: I have checked it.But it is not much clear to me.I want some sample coding on how to connect to external database(I use MySQL workbench)

Comment: Use web services to GET/POST data from/to server. To call web services in phonegap use `$.ajax`

Comment: here Amol .Im doing this as part of my 3rd year project.But actually I'm a Network Engineering student and have less idea about programming .It would be a great help if you can give me little bit more guidance.  thnx in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your app will reside on a device(android/iOS).
So it will be a client side, more like a browser.

And you have communicate to server for getting or posting data.

You must be aware of that, phonegap use jQuery and javascript.

So as I told earlier, if you want to communicate with remote server
you will have to call web services in your app using javascript.

**Your approach should be:**

**Server Side:**

Create the web services using your server side language.

Assuming you are using **PHP** as a server side language.
Refer following links

1. [Creating PHP web services Tutorial](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json)
2. [Creating PHP web services PPT](http://www.slideshare.net/lornajane/web-services-13234948)

**Client Side:**

Then you can use `$ajax` to fetch data from server 
or post data to server.

As far as `$ajax` call concerns, check out the following sample code.

```
function FetchData() {
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: "Your_WebService_URL",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $.each(data, function(i, object) {
            alert(obj.Data);
            //Here you can implement your client side logic.
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("There was an error loading the feed");
    }
});
```

}

I assume it will be at least a kick start.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thnx a lot ,I have created a web form to connect to my database.I want to connect the database externally.Is there a way to convert web form to  web service?

Comment: Are you using PHP as a server side language?

Comment: yeah and i got to know wampserver is better to code php.There is a web form i have created .Can i use it as a web service using php to connect to external database?

Comment: I am not much familiar with PHP but, I suspect you cannot use the web form as it is because web service must return data in `xml/json` format. But you can always reuse the code of web form in web service. Refer the links I have provided in above answer.

Comment: hey I asked from a lecturer and thought of using c# in visual studio.U think that's a good idea.I think i can use windows services there.I use Visual studio 2010 :) .What you think???

Comment: I suspect you cannot consume windows services in phonegap app. You can create `web services using ASP.NET`

Comment: ohh ok so are you saying we can use web services instead windows servises to connect to both database and phonegap app?? web services also available in visual studio :)

Comment: Yes. Your app will connect to a database using web service.

Comment: thnx :) hope I'l be able to get little help if get stuck :)

Comment: Sure :) anytime. And Good Luck!! with your project. :)

Comment: thnx :) hey Amol,in Visual studio,there is a thing called WCF services,not web services,Is it the same?? Can you send me a link or tell me a way to create this web service in VS2010?? or do i have to use any other software?I just need a boost for the start.No need the whole coding stuff...thank you :)

Comment: Yes in `.NET` there are` WCF services` and `ASMX web services`. **Refer these links:** [1. Differences Between ASMX and WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648181.aspx) [2. Another link for Difference](http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2012/06/wcf-vs-asmx-web-services.html) [3. Creating ASMX web services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45275/Create-a-JSON-WebService-in-ASP-NET-2-0-with-a-jQu) [4. Creating WCF web services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327420/WCF-REST-Service-with-JSON). Hope that helps

Comment: thnq :) btw can $ajax messages work with WCF?? In those tutorials they say it is compatible with any.just to make sure :)