# How to sync data with PhoneGap?

Tags: database, html, cordova, synchronization, android

I am making an Android application project using **HTML5**, **CSS**, **JS** and **PhoneGap** 
but I don't understand how to sync data between my application and my **MySQL** database.

How can data be synced between MySQL and an Android application?

Comment: Which database do you use ?

Comment: I am using MySQL database

Comment: It looks like you are not very familiar with the concept of cordova and frontend <--> backend. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690111/connecting-to-an-external-databse-with-phonegap-android-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a server, could be Apache with PHP and MySQL installed. Create the tables and add the data. Then in your PhoneGap app, use AJAX to pull those data.

Comment: I am not sure PhoneGap Application can use PHP and MySQL?